# How to ensure unmodifiable document checksum?

Tags: encryption, cryptography

Scenario: I need to store document accepted by the customer in my database. Customer needs to be sure that I don't modify it through time, and I need to have possibility to prove that stored document was accepted by the customer. 
Do you know proven ways how to achieve this without doubts from any side?

I think I can create checksum from stored data for the customer, but I need to ensure that this checksum is unmodifiable by the customer. Any ideas?

PS. If you have better idea how to title this question then tell me, please.

PS. Let me know if you see better forum to ask this question, please.

Comment: isn't this one of the problem blockchain solves?

Comment: Sounds to me like a crypto question more suitable for [Crypto](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) than a programming question for stackoverflow.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I didn't know about Crypto. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we call this in Cryptography is [data integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity).

To ensure that the data is not changed by you or someone else, your customer can calculate the hash of the file with a [cryptographic hash functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function), which are designed to have collision resistance. I.e.

```
 Hash(Original) != Hash(Modified) // equality almost impossible
```

In short, when you modify it is expected that the new modified document has the same hash value is impossible (in Cryptology term, negligible).

Your customer can use [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) hash function which is standardized by [NIST](https://www.nist.gov/news-events/news/2015/08/nist-releases-sha-3-cryptographic-hash-standard).

Don't use SHA-1 which has [shattered](https://shattered.io/).

If you want to go further, your customer can use [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC) which are key-based hash functions which supply data integrity and the [authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication) of data.

---

For the second part, we can solve it by [digital signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signature). Your customer signs the message

```
 Sign(hash(message))
```

and gives you

```
 ( Sign(hash(message)), message ) )
```

and his public key.

You can verify the signature with the public key of the customer to see that the customer changed the data or not. Digital signatures gives us [Non-Repudation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation).

This part actually solves your two problems. Even third parties can check that the data is not modified and comes from the signer (your customer).

---

**Note :** don't use checksums which are not Cryptographically secure and mostly easy to modify the document in a way that they have the same checksums.

Comment: Checksum for the customer ensures that I won't modify data. What about scenario when the customer modifies checksum and says that stored document is tampered? I could encrypt checksum and then check if his data can be decrypted my way. What do you think? Or SHA supports such thing?

Comment: @Bogdan modified.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to stop answering the crypto questions here and instead flag them for movement to crypto?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Yup, my mistake.